# Android UI Tests with Storage Permissions in CI

Tags: android, jenkins-pipeline, ui-testing

I want to run UI tests and unit tests on a project in CI (Jenkins Pipeline). The UI tests requires images and video to be on the test device / emulator. In the UI tests I request permission for storage read/write access so I can dump a few assets into the downloads folder, then at the end of the test suite I remove them.

When I run my tests on Jenkins (mac) permissions are not granted, no media transfers over, and all of my tests fail.

The project contains an app module and two in-house library modules.

## Pipeline steps

**Build**

```
sh "./gradlew clean assembleRelease"
```

**Unit Test**

```
sh "./gradlew testReleaseUnitTest"
```

**UI Test**

```
sh "$ANDROID_HOME/emulator/emulator @my_sweet_emulator_name -no-boot-anim & $ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools/adb wait-for-device"
sh './gradlew connectedAndroidTest'
```

## Issues

1) The CI build hangs on the implicit `assembleDebugAndroidTest` task

2) If I run that task on the command line on my computer the tests will install however the permission is not granted to read/write storage so all tests fail due to not having any expected content on the device.

## Things I've Tried

- I have attempted only testing a release build however this shows the same issue 2. `testBuildType "release"`
- I have no other permissions I need to work with

How I'm granting permissions

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class MyMediaClassTest {

    @Rule
    @JvmField
    val activityRule = ActivityTestRule(MainActivity::class.java)

    @Rule
    @JvmField
    val grantPermissionRule: GrantPermissionRule = GrantPermissionRule
            .grant(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                    android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
// tests and stuff
}
```

I have seen a short-term solution to manually copy all of my media assets into the emulator. But that doesn't seem right, this should be able to be automated.

Comment: Could you post the exception that is showing when the test fails? Also are you sure that you can create files in the emulator? Probably the storage was created with the sdcard/emulated folder being not writable... Try downloading a file from website in Chrome within the emulator to make sure

Comment: @ahasbini 1) the tests fail due to no media on the device, so the stacktrace here won't help. 2) I am able to manually copy files to the device (drag and drop) and then everything "is okay"

Comment: I've given it a try the way your trying (drag and drop) and found the files to be copied to `/sdcard/Downloads`. Are you able to confirm that the files are being copied into the emulator? It'll be helpful to confirm using the command `adb shell` and `cd /sdcard/Downloads' in order to confirm that the files are there using `ls -la` command.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that the files exist once I drag and drop onto the emulator. However that's not what I want to do, that is a workaround. The ideal solution is for that to be automated with the UI tests. The ideal steps are: 
1) before test grant permission and copy media to emulator. 2) run tests. 3) delete media from emulator

Comment: This looks more like an issue with the code to copy the files over. That's why a stacktrace and the relevant code. Instead of `@Rule @JvmField` I usually use `@get:Rule`.

Comment: @Sababado, totally agree with you, just needed to confirm certain things which came to top of my mind. I've tried it out myself as I work with Java instead of Kotlin and have found that the same concept is applied. Have provided an answer showing my findings.

Answer (score 2):

The way it worked with me is by following the below steps:

Added the permissions in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file of my `app` module.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

And have tried executing the below instrumented test cases/class:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class ExampleInstrumentedTest {

    @Rule
    @JvmField
    val grantPermissionRule: GrantPermissionRule = GrantPermissionRule
            .grant(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                    android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)

    val rootDir = "/sdcard/"

    @Test
    fun testTargetContextPermission() {
        val targetContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext()
        assertTrue("Not the target package",
                !targetContext.packageName.endsWith(".test"))
        assertTrue("Permissions not Granted", targetContext.checkSelfPermission(
                android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                targetContext.checkSelfPermission(
                        android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        val file = File(rootDir + "targetTest.txt")
        if (file.exists()) {
            file.delete()
        }
        assertTrue("File was not created", file.createNewFile())
        val sdcard = File(rootDir)
        assertTrue("sdcard is empty or file not found", sdcard.list().size != 0 &&
                Arrays.asList<String>(*sdcard.list()).contains("targetTest.txt"))
    }

    @Test
    fun testInstrumentationPermission() {
        val instrumentationContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getContext()
        assertTrue("Not the instrumentation package",
                instrumentationContext.packageName.endsWith(".test"))
        assertTrue("Permissions not Granted", instrumentationContext.checkSelfPermission(
                android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                instrumentationContext.checkSelfPermission(
                        android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        val file = File(rootDir + "instrumentationTest.txt")
        if (file.exists()) {
            file.delete()
        }
        assertTrue("File was not created", file.createNewFile())
        val sdcard = File(rootDir)
        assertTrue("sdcard is empty or file not found", sdcard.list().size != 0 &&
                Arrays.asList<String>(*sdcard.list()).contains("instrumentationTest.txt"))
    }
}
```

Both test cases returned with success. Upon changing `rootDir` to `"/"`, the tests failed since the `/` directory is a read-only which is expected.

The idea behind having two test cases is to test the different `Context` which the tests could retrieve at runtime. The `testTargetContextPermission` uses the app `Context` which **does not** have it's package name or application id ending with `.test`. While the `testInstrumentationPermission` uses the instrumentation app `Context` which **does** have it's package name or application id ending with `.test`. I thought that permissions need to be defined in each of their `AndroidManifest`s but turns out that defining the permissions for your `app` `AndroidManifest` only will automatically give the same permissions to the Instrumentation package as well.